# Trying to use sheet index in cell formula

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a workbook called "Pink File".  There are many cells that I want to copy and paste into another file called Customers.  I have this formula in Customers B2 cell:

```
='[Pink File.xlsx]Mar 18'!$G$3
```

Instead of the sheet in Pink File being called out as Mar 18, I want that to be `Worksheets(1)`, but that doesn't work.

Every month, a new sheet is entered, with all new data, but the sheet name is all that changes.  The location of all the data is the same.  So when next months numbers come out, they will be (Pink File) in a sheet called Apr 2.

So if my new book always reference the 1st sheet, my data should always be updated.

But is this possible?

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Not easily possible. You cannot put Worksheets(1) into a formula but you can put Mar 18, Apr 18 etc. However if you have to build that name dynamically, you would need INDIRECT and indirect cxannot be used on a closed worksheet/workbook.

Comment: Can you not just loop through the sheets in **Pink File.xlsx** and get the name that way? (although this would mean you will need VBA..)

Comment: Hmmm....OK, so what I can do is copy all off sheet 1, paste into new sheet and name it the same every time.  Then in the other file, use that sheet name as the reference which will auto update.  An extra step but not horrible.  Anyone see any pitfalls in that?

Comment: Seems ok to me... ( :